# Consecutive numbering in theorem enviroments, inside framed boxes

Tags: numbering, environments, theorems, tcolorbox, framed

I want to write propositions, lemmas, theorems,
corollaries inside the chosen boxes and definitions NOT inside boxes, all of them with consecutive numbering. I searched for similar posts and I found things, but all were without boxes.

So,

1) Any ideas to fix this issue?

2) Is there a way to write "theorem 1.0.1" instead of "1.0.1 theorem" in these boxes?

Example: Theorem 1.0.1, Definition 1.0.2. Lemma 1.0.3, Definition 1.0.4,...

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{udidot}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{thm}{Θεώρημα}{
  theorem style=change apart,
  enhanced jigsaw,% <--- jigsaw
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0pt,
  toprule=1pt,bottomrule=1pt,
  left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,top=0.2cm,
  titlerule=0.5em,
  toptitle=0.1cm,
  bottomtitle=-0.1cm,
  colframe=white!25!black,colback=white,coltitle=white,
  %title style={white!25!black},   & <---- remove
  fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize}{thm}

  \newtcbtheorem[number within=thm]{prop}{Πρόταση}{
  theorem style=change apart,
  enhanced jigsaw,% <--- jigsaw
  sharp corners,
  boxrule=0pt,
  toprule=1pt,bottomrule=1pt,
  left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,top=0.2cm,
  titlerule=0.5em,
  toptitle=0.1cm,
  bottomtitle=-0.1cm,
  colframe=white!25!black,colback=white,coltitle=white,
  %title style={white!25!black},   & <---- remove
  fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize}{prop}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Hi}
\begin{thm}{\greektext Stokes}{stokes}
Let $D$ be a regular domain in an oriented $n$-dimensional manifold $M$,
and let $\omega$ be a smooth $(n-1)$ form of compact support. Then
\[\int_D d\omega = \int_{\partial D} \omega.\] \greektext Και δηλαδή τι άλλα;
\end{thm}

\begin{prop}{}{}
sdfasdasdasd
\end{prop}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Comment `theorem style=change apart,` to swap theorem and number.

Comment: @Sigur Thank you for your comment. Any ideas for the consecutive numbering?

Comment: I never used this package, but I think the key point is the `number within`, which looks right to me. Strange. Lets wait some experienced user.

Comment: Nobody? :( :( :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the consecutive numbering, use the option `use counter from={...}`.

To have definitions not inside boxes, you could create a non-box with `tcolorbox`.

As Sigur wrote in his/her comment, to write "theorem 1.0.1" instead of "1.0.1 theorem" just leave out `theorem style=change apart`.

You can easily find all this option in the very well done [`tcolorbox` package manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{udidot}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{thm}{\greektext Θεώρημα}{
    %  theorem style=change apart,
      enhanced jigsaw,% <--- jigsaw
      sharp corners,
      boxrule=0pt,
      toprule=1pt,
      bottomrule=1pt,
      left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,top=0.2cm,
      titlerule=0.5em,
      toptitle=0.1cm,
      bottomtitle=-0.1cm,
      colframe=white!25!black,colback=white,coltitle=white,
      %title style={white!25!black},   & <---- remove
      fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize}{thm}

  \newtcbtheorem[number within=section,use counter from=thm]{prop}{\greektext Πρόταση}{
     % theorem style=change apart,
      enhanced jigsaw,% <--- jigsaw
      sharp corners,
      boxrule=0pt,
      toprule=1pt,bottomrule=1pt,
      left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,top=0.2cm,
      titlerule=0.5em,
      toptitle=0.1cm,
      bottomtitle=-0.1cm,
      colframe=white!25!black,colback=white,coltitle=white,
      %title style={white!25!black},   & <---- remove
      fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize}{prop}

 \newtcbtheorem[number within=section,use counter from=thm]{defin}{Definition}{
      boxrule=0pt,
      boxsep=0pt,
      left=0pt,right=0pt,
      titlerule=0pt,
      colframe=white,
      coltitle=black,
      colbacktitle=white,
      colback=white,
      fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize}{defin}

\begin{document}
     \selectlanguage{english}
    \chapter{Hi}
    \begin{thm}{\greektext Stokes}{stokes}
    Let $D$ be a regular domain in an oriented $n$-dimensional manifold $M$,
    and let $\omega$ be a smooth $(n-1)$ form of compact support. Then
    \[\int_D d\omega = \int_{\partial D} \omega.\] \greektext Και δηλαδή τι άλλα;
    \end{thm}

    \begin{prop}{}{}
    sdfasdasdasd
    \end{prop}

    \begin{defin}{}{}
    The definition is not boxed
    \end{defin}
\end{document}
```

[image]